# Importance Sampling - Monte Carlo Integration

Tags: r, integration, simulation, probability, montecarlo

I am trying to implement Monte Carlo integration with importance sampling. I've created a trivial example 
- I wish to integrate h(x), which is has a student t-distribution (mu =1, sigma =1, df=100), but us scaled-up 4 times 
- I want to integrate over the interval [-2,2] 
- f(x), the pdf of my h(x), is  then t(1,1,100) 
- my proposal distribution is g(x), and normal (0,1)

I can't get this work... I am confused with how to implement Importance Sampling and using a probability-density-function for h(x) and a proposal distribution g(x). I'm sure my implementation is wrong. I was hoping someone could please help me?

```
xtemp<-rnorm(100000) 
x<-xtemp[which(xtemp>=-2 & xtemp<=2)] 
hx<-dt(x,100)*4
fx<-dt(x,100) 
gx<-dnorm(x) 

IntMC<-sum(hx*fx/gx)/length(hx) 
IntAn <-(pt(2,100)-pt(-2,100))*4
```

Comment: What is IS? pdf? Get rid of acronims, please.

Comment: I'm going to go out on a limb and guess that IS means Importance Sampling, and pdf is Probability Density Function.

Comment: edits done, pdf = probability density function, IS = importance sampling

Comment: I'd recommend taking a little time to read Numerical Recipes in C.  There are pdf versions available for download. You don't have to use the c-code, as the algorithms themselves are presented in excellent detail.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are sampling from a *truncated* normal distribution, you should not use the probability density function of the normal distribution (`dnorm` in your example) but of the *truncated normal* distribution (e.g., `dtnorm` from the package `msm`) for the computation of the weights.

Try the following, it gives you the expected result:

```
library(msm)  # provides the pdf of the truncated normal distribution

xtemp <- rnorm(100000) 
x <- xtemp[which(xtemp>=-2 & xtemp<=2)] 

hx <- dt(x,100)*4
gx <- dtnorm(x, lower=-2, upper=2) 

IntMC <- mean(hx/gx) 
IntAn <- (pt(2,100)-pt(-2,100))*4
```